# Postgresql - Basic Arrays and array_agg

Tags: postgresql

As a Test I created this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE simple_table (client_id int4, order_id int4);
INSERT INTO simple_table (client_id, order_id) 
VALUES 
(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,6),(1,8),(1,12),(1,16),(1,18),(1,25),(1,32),(1,33),(1,37),(1,43),
(1,56),(1,57),(1,66),(2,2),(2,3),(2,5),(2,7),(2,9),(2,12),(2,17),(2,19),(2,22),(2,30),
(2,33),(2,38),(2,44),(2,56),(2,58),(2,66)
;
```

Then used array_agg:

```
SELECT client_id, array_agg(order_id) FROM simple_table GROUP BY client_id;
```

to create the arrays for client 1 and client 2:

```
| CLIENT_ID |                                  ARRAY_AGG |
----------------------------------------------------------
|         1 | 2,3,4,6,8,12,16,18,25,32,33,37,43,56,57,66 |
|         2 | 2,3,5,7,9,12,17,19,22,30,33,38,44,56,58,66 |
```

Now I would like to compare the 2 rows and identify the like values.  Tried `&&     overlap (have elements in common) ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1]` from the Postgresql documentation but I am having problems.


Perhaps I am looking at this wrong. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for including sample data and what you're trying to achieve, +1. It'd be good if you could show exactly what problems you are having (unexpected results, error message, etc) and the *exact* text of the SQL you ran, though. Finally, please always include your PostgreSQL version (`SELECT version()`) in questions.

Comment: Sorry.  9.2 on OSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&&` operator is a predicate that yields a `true` or `false` result, not a list of values.

If you're looking for the list of `order_id` that exist for both `client_id=1` and `client_id=2`, the query would be:

```
 select order_id from simple_table  where client_id in (1,2)
  group by order_id having count(*)=2;
```

That's equivalent to the intersections of the two arrays if you consider that these arrays are sets (no duplicates and the positions of the values are irrelevant), except that you don't need to use arrays at all, simple standard SQL is good enough.

Comment: PERFECT!!  Exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks Daniel!  So if I had multiple client_ids:
`where client_id in (1,2)`
would I write:
`where client_id in (1,2,3,4)`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "array_intersect" functions here:
[Array Intersect](http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#Intersection_of_arrays)

To see elements that are *not* common to both arrays:

```
create or replace function arrxor(anyarray,anyarray) returns anyarray as $$
select ARRAY(
        (
        select r.elements
        from    (
                (select 1,unnest($1))
                union all
                (select 2,unnest($2))
                ) as r (arr, elements)
        group by 1
        having min(arr) = max(arr)
        )
)
$$ language sql strict immutable;
```