# Dynamic cross join per group

Tags: postgresql

I have the following postgres table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Group        |      Product     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          |         P1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          |         P2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          B          |         Q1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          B          |         Q2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          B          |         Q3       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          C          |         R1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          C          |         R2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to write a query that outputs the following:

```
|---------------------|
|        Array        |
|---------------------|
|      {P1,Q1,R1}     |
|---------------------|
|      {P1,Q2,R1}     |
|---------------------|
|      {P1,Q3,R1}     |
|---------------------|
|      {P1,Q1,R2}     |
|---------------------|
|      {P1,Q2,R2}     |
|---------------------|
|      {P1,Q3,R2}     |
|---------------------|
|      {P2,Q1,R1}     |
|---------------------|
|      {P2,Q2,R1}     |
|---------------------|
|      {P2,Q3,R1}     |
|---------------------|
|      {P2,Q1,R2}     |
|---------------------|
|      {P2,Q2,R2}     |
|---------------------|
|      {P2,Q3,R2}     |
|---------------------|
```

That means that the source data needs to result in 12 (2x3x2) rows. The number of groups and products per group is variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql - Basic Arrays and array\_agg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436632/postgresql-basic-arrays-and-array-agg)

Comment: I would suggest to make a query that outputs all groups with an array of products for each, then implement the cartesian product yourself in client code.

Comment: I don't think so. As I understand it the query is just a grouping and filter but doesn't "multiply" the set of records. I need to make 12 records out of 7. @JorgeCampos

Comment: @Bergi: Maybe I'll do that but actually I wanted to avoid client code for this. I'll wait for a bit - maybe there is somebody who can solve it. Thanks!

Comment: @microman You can also implement the cartesian product in postgres using a recursive function, but I thought it would be simpler (and more efficient) not do that (unless you need the result inside the database). Alternatively, with a recursive CTE like Mike has just done…

Comment: @Bergi: You're right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it recursively:

```
with recursive groupnums as (
  select distinct grp from gp
), numbering as (
  select grp, row_number() over (order by grp) gnum
    from groupnums
), numbered as (
  select n.gnum, gp.grp, gp.product
    from numbering n
    join gp on gp.grp = n.grp
), exploded as (
  select gnum, grp, product, array[product] as parray
    from numbered
   where gnum = 1
  union all
  select n.gnum, n.grp, n.product, e.parray||n.product
    from numbered n
    join exploded e on e.gnum = n.gnum - 1
)
select parray
  from exploded
 where gnum = (select max(gnum) from numbering)
 order by parray;

   parray   
------------
 {P1,Q1,R1}
 {P1,Q1,R2}
 {P1,Q2,R1}
 {P1,Q2,R2}
 {P1,Q3,R1}
 {P1,Q3,R2}
 {P2,Q1,R1}
 {P2,Q1,R2}
 {P2,Q2,R1}
 {P2,Q2,R2}
 {P2,Q3,R1}
 {P2,Q3,R2}
(12 rows)
```

Comment: I would suggest not to select `grp` and `product` columns in `exploded` at all. Also you can start the recursive query with `SELECT 0 as gnum, '{}' as parray` as a base case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This returns exactly the expected result! Thanks a lot Mike @MikeOrganek

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, will do that!